# How can I use End-to-end encryption in sensors network?

Tags: security, networking, sensors

I have been reading about XMPP and its extensions. One of them called ([XEP-xxxx: Sensor-Over-XMPP](https://xmpp.org/extensions/inbox/sensors.html)) which is really interesting.

I have read also about another XMPP extension which is [OMEMO protocol](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0384.html) for End-to-end encryption.

Is it possible to combine both? to have sensor data that End-to-end encrypted? And what are the considerations that I should take into account?

Comment: Why you want to encrypt sensor data at first place??

Comment: Because of these data are important for example https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/683/7138

Comment: Nice examples and explanation but do you really think that you need encryption in your system. Thats what I wanted to ask.

Comment: I honestly don't know .. What my question was about is the check the possibility to have end to end encryption .. Implementing such a system is not my priority at this point

Comment: Than i ll try my level best to answer your queries

Comment: You can use open-source ssh to encrypt your data. There is free implementation from  https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable. I did not try it but i believe it is very good for your project.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should be encrypting your sensor messages.

No, you shouldn't be thinking about using a roll-your-own approach to add encryption on top of an existing re-used protocol.

Security isn't just about the messages, you ideally want to trust the server, to trust your firmware updates, etc.

The easy way around this is to use a full device firmware stack which already provides some guarantees about security, aimed specifically at IoT applications. Rather than encrypting your sensor data, you probably want to use a secure channel (for everything). TLS seems to be the default answer to this.

Related [question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1517).

Answer (score 1):

Please consider to use [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/)  because that platform will give you option to have end2end encryption and can carry messages across inproc, IPC, TCP, TIPC, multicast. In addition - it is really tiny library with interfaces ready for many programming languages.

When we are about security please check out bellow:

The core C/C+++ library implements the NULL and PLAIN mechanisms (those were easy), and also CURVE and GSSAPI (rather harder). CURVE is the CurveZMQ.org protocol [for authentication and encryption](http://zeromq.org/docs:features). GSSAPI lets us plug into Kerberos. 
The core library has an authentication API called "ZAP" that lets you add, e.g. your own IP address blacklisting at the connection level.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I will check it out. However, that doesn't really answer the question

Comment: in the FAQ of ZeroQ it's written (What security features does ZeroMQ support?

None at the moment but this is being added to the next version of the protocol. People have successfully built DTLS, CurveCP, and other security protocols over ZeroMQ.)